# ApacheDS - cannot verify the quality of the non-cleartext passwords

Tags: apache, ldap, md5, apacheds

I'm getting `cannot verify the quality of the non-cleartext passwords` error while trying to add an entry into my organizationalUnit. I use **MD5** hashing method while storing password. (with `userPassword` attribute)

[A blog post](http://thuberv7.blogspot.com/2012/10/apacheds-default-passwordpolicies.html) says the solution is adding `ads-pwdcheckquality` attribute with value of 0; but it didn't work for me. And also while trying to add this attribute; it gives a warning like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add a new attribute, you need to edit the server configuration and restart:

1-Open config.ldif in the server folder, search for the string:

`ads-pwdcheckquality: 2`

and change it to:

`ads-pwdcheckquality: 0`

2-After that, restart the server and try again. The solution worked for me.

Comment: The answer above works, but please note that in ApacheDS 2 the attribute is called:
ads-pwdCheckQuality (ie it is camel-case, not all lower-case)

Comment: Where exactly is this file located?  I'm using apache-2.0.0-M8, and I can't find the file.

Comment: Found it at: /var/lib/apacheds-2.0.0-M8/default/conf and Rafael thanks for the tip on the camelCase